# Using R to store column data into vectors

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, import, rstudio

I have a file composed of columns of data imported into **R** Studio:

Column 1: ##Days0 12 12 12  (##Days0 is the header in row 1 and the following numbers are the independent variables from row 2:4)

Column 2: ##Concentration0 1 2 3 (##Concentration0 is the header in row 1 and the following numbers are the data points from row 2:4)

Column 3: ##Days 24 24 24  (##Days is the header in row 1 and the following numbers are the independent variables from row 2:4)

Column 4: ##Concentration 3 8 5 (##Concentration is the header in row 1 and the following numbers are the data points from row 2:4)

I am trying to write a code that automatically takes the data under each column of an imported file with any arbitrary number of columns and stores them as vectors. I tried using `colnames(`) to obtain the headers that I could then call as vectors using `$header` but that returns the headers as strings. I have also attempted to pull the data off the file using a for loop but that failed too. I cannot figure out a way to do this; any ideas? I would appreciate the help!

Here's my attempt:

```
Test_1 <- read.csv("~/Documents/Summer Research Folder 2014 /B.csv",quote="")

b=colnames(Test_1, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = NONE)

Test_1$b 

### Test_1$ returns null as an output
```

Answer (score 0):

This may give you a basic idea on what you can do. Just replace 'print' with any other operator you need.

```
a1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a2 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
a3 = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
df = data.frame(a1, a2, a3)

cn <- colnames(df)
v <- vector()

for(i in cn) {
    v <- df[,i]
    print(v)
}
```

I am not sure what you want to do further with your vectors, but frankly speaking you may already treat your data frame AS a collection of vertical vectors with data :) You can access them as `Test_1[, ColumnName]` Hope this may help you.